# Why are the timezone offset returning different values?

Tags: c#, javascript

My location is at GMT +5:30

When I try to find `getTimezoneOffset` using JavaScript

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

I get the value `-5.5`. Curiously, when I am doing the same using C#

```
var localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
var localOffset = localZone.GetUtcOffset(new Date());
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = localOffset.TotalHours;
```

The return value is `5.5`.

Is this sign change by design or am I missing anything important?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JavaScript's `getTimeZoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) returns the offset to be added to *local* time to get to UTC. (The description of "the time-zone offset from UTC" is misleading, IMO.)

.NET's `GetUtcOffset` returns the offset to be added to the *UTC* time to get to local time, which is the more conventional approach IMO. It's just a different point of reference, basically.

Note that if you're using .NET 3.5 or later, you should really be using [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) instead of `TimeZone`.